# Is creating new instances of class in the class itself a bad practice?

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

i need to create a pointer to a new class in the class itself. is this a bad practice?

```
class A {
public:
    A* createNewClass() {
        return new A();
    }
 };

int main() {
    A a;
    A* b = a.createNewClass();
    A* c = a.createNewClass();
    // ... and create more classes this way
}
```

Comment: If it was a bad practice, a whole bunch of production quality code the contains `clone` functions would be in deep trouble.

Comment: I don't see any problem with it, using raw pointers, on the other hand...

Comment: The biggest problem is the misuse of the word "class". Classes are types, not objects.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, although for this specific case, I think it should have been a static function

Comment: I think a little bit of context would be good. Why do you need it, and how do you call the method?

Comment: it is hard to say if it is bad practice or not without other hints, but in general I find very useful to try to answer the question: what is the enhancement with that? Would people understand how to use this class, or should they look at the implementation details to use it as I would like them to use it? In general, you have freedom, but try to use that freedom to make your intentions super clear, and that will be usually more important than adhering blindly to some non written rule :)